# how to return data to outer scope in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, alexa-skills-kit

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
      function getNameAndWelcome(callback) {
        request(amznProfileURL,function (error, response, body) {
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var profile = JSON.parse(body);
            let name = profile.name.split(" ")[0];
            const speechText = `Welcome to the real estate skill ${name}, you can enquire about properties in various cities like Austin.`;
            Response = handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Real Estate', speechText)
            .getResponse();
          }else{
            const speechText = `Welcome to the real estate skill, you can enquire about properties in various cities like Austin.`;
            Response = handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Real Estate', speechText)
            .getResponse();
          }
          callback(Response);
        })
      }
      return getNameAndWelcome(function(res){
        return res;
      });
    }else{
      const speechText = 'Hi there! This skill requires account linking. Please follow the steps sent on the alexa application in your mobile.';

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withLinkAccountCard()
      .getResponse();
    } 
  }
};
```

This is a code snippet on which I have been banging my head all day long.I am trying to return the object in the variable "Response" to the "handle" function.I hope it is clear from the code what I have tried. Basically I am sending a callback which I hope will return the "Response" object to the function "getNameAndWelcome" and then I can return that again to the outer scope  but as you can guess it does not work. Where am I making a mistake?Thanks.

This is the part where I register my handlers.

```
    exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  if (!skill) {
    skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
      LaunchRequestHandler,
      LocationIntentHandler,
      StatusIntentHandler,
      GeneralIntentHandler,
      QAIntentHandler,
      LowestPriceIntentHandler,
      HighestPriceIntentHandler,
      HelpIntentHandler,
      CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
      SessionEndedRequestHandler,
      )
    .addRequestInterceptors(AccessTokenInterceptor)
    .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
    .withSkillId(skillId)
    .create();
  }

  return skill.invoke(event,context);
}
```

Comment: Write response in low case, maybe there is an interference with the Response class of the API. Otherwise it seems like a asynchronous thing as stated before.

Comment: Can you post the part where you register your handlers?

Comment: @sascha10000 sure give me a sec

Comment: @sascha10000 added.please check

Comment: Okay on the first look it looks quite okay. Have you tried to debug the code, like adding an console.log(Response) after the creation before calling the callback. It may be undefined...

Comment: cloudwatch logs just say that session ended with an error....i did console.log(Response) but the execution never reached that part.

Comment: Find out where your code crashes. Then check if each condition for the success of the "crashing" call is met, like parameters in case of a fuction call.

Comment: You are calling the function recursively.... This will result in an error....

Comment: sorry i didn't get you...where is the recursion?